# How can calculate "vki" in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

We have a table like this:

```
HospitalCode    kcode   k 
------------------------------
234             COO1    0.5
234             COO1    0.5
234             C002    2.4
234             C003    1.5 
123             C001    0.5
345             C004    1.0  
567             C001    2.2
345             C002    3.0
567             C002    2.4
```

We want to calculate vki of HospitalCode.vki calculate formula this is:

```
vki=(k*count(kcode))/totalCount(kcode)
```

For example if we want to calculate vki's in this table, this will like this:

vki for 234 of HospitalCode:

```
(count of kcode is about  in this table)

counts  kcode of 234:

C001:2
C002:1
C003:1



vkiFor234=(2*0.5+1*1.5+1*2.4)/4=2.4
```

So we should calculate  for every Hospital Code.

I tried this SQL Server Code:

```
SELECT HospitalCode,SUM(COUNT(kcode)*k)/COUNT(kcode) FROM myTable
GROUP BY HospitalCode
```

But this isnt work.

How can we do this?

Thanks

Comment: why this does not work? any error message?

Comment: why do you calculate the `sum` of `SUM(COUNT(kcode)*k)`? This doesnt match your own vki formula.

Comment: this works but its giving wrong result.

Comment: JaMaBig You may right.But How can we give this formula

Comment: Are you sure that the answer must be 2.4? Because I calculate it to be 1.225?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your 2.4, even if I calculate it on a calculator, and this code produce the result to the same value I've calculated.

Here is two ways that you can do it

```
SELECT HospitalCode, SUM(Total) from
(Select distinct HospitalCode, (COUNT(kcode) OVER(PARTITION BY kcode order by HospitalCode) * k / COUNT(HospitalCode) 
OVER(PARTITION BY HospitalCode order by HospitalCode)) AS Total from myTable) a
GROUP BY HospitalCode 
ORDER BY HospitalCode
```

or

```
Select HospitalCode, SUM(kcnt * k) / MAX(tcnt) from
(Select HospitalCode, kcode, k, Count(*) kcnt, (Select Count(*) from myTable where HospitalCode = a.HospitalCode) tcnt from myTable a
GROUP BY HospitalCode, kcode, k) a
GROUP BY HospitalCode
order by 1
```

Comment: I have tested the execution plan for both of your queries, the last one is the most effective.